# Does free deallocate all the memory of a larger struct pointer from a smaller one?

Tags: c, struct, free

So, I am trying to implement a polymorphic system in C, similar to that of PyObject and the Python object system. However, I am having trouble understanding how a struct cast from a base struct can be freed. I have implemented the following base and advanced struct types:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

//testing for garbage collection

//base handler to ensure polymorphism
#define BASE char g;

struct temp {
  BASE
  short w;
};

struct femp {
  BASE
  short w;
  long d;
};


int main(void) {
  struct femp* first = malloc(sizeof(struct femp));
  first->d = 3444;
  struct temp* second = (struct temp*)first;
  free(second); // does this deallocate all the memory of first?
  free(first);
  return 0;
}
```

*note*: The above program exits with nonzero status if second is freed, but not first.

result:

```
7fb829d02000-7fb829d04000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb829d0c000-7fb829d10000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fb829d10000-7fb829d11000 r--p 00023000 00:136 38                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7fb829d11000-7fb829d12000 rw-p 00024000 00:136 38                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
7fb829d12000-7fb829d13000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffac407000-7fffac428000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffac499000-7fffac49b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fffac49b000-7fffac49d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
exited with non-zero status
```

My question is, does calling `free()` on a pointer to a smaller sized struct, which is casted from an original malloc'd larger size struct, still free all of the memory? like in my code, is there any difference from freeing first or second? Should you always cast back to the original type before freeing?

Comment: You don't "allocate structures", you allocate amounts of memory. Malloc takes an integer argument which is a number of bytes. Free just frees however many bytes that was. Neither knows anything about structures.

Comment: `free` is taking a pointer to `void`. So it really doesn't care what it was casted to before.

Comment: ok so this would mean you have to free() whatever sized struct was originally malloc'd then? correct?

Comment: @JoshWeinstein, `free` doesn't care about structs or chars or anything. It simply frees the memory a pointer points to, that's all.

Comment: Yes but the above program in my question exits with non zero status if i free a pointer to a struct thats casted from a larger struct (second in this case), which what prompted me to ask this.

Comment: When you are coming to  a bank and ask for $1000 credit for general purpose and bank is giving you it, it doesn't care have you spent just $800 of them and kept $200, or spent all of them. It will still ask you to return the full amount (+interest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc()` / `free()` know nothing at all about your structures. `malloc()` takes an integer argument and allocates that many bytes, giving you a memory address. `free()` takes that address, and frees whatever was allocated. What you do with it in the meantime is up to you.

If you need some memory that might possibly hold one of two things, it's up to you to make sure it's big enough. If you allocate a 5-gallon bucket and only use it to carry 3 gallons, that's fine. If you try to carry 7 gallons, you'll get your feet wet. C will not interfere with you doing either.

Comment: ok this makes sense, but why does in this case freeing the pointer to a smaller struct cause non-zero status?

Comment: Because you're freeing the same address twice.